# how can Parser a file(ini) include "AT" by python

Tags: python, ini

```
[db_finding]
cluster_name  :  db_finding
connect_timeout_ms  :  900

[.@host]
ip  :  10.1.7.71
port  :  6500

[.@host]
ip  :  10.1.7.65
port  :  6500
```

I can use :

```
val = cf.get("db_finding",'cluster_name')
```

It's worked.

But how can I get "AT" host?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.. Took me a bit. I like it :D The solutions out there are not very robust.

```
import ConfigParser

class MultiOrderedDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self and isinstance(value, list):
            self[key].append(value[0])
            return

        super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict)
config.read(['cluster.conf'])
print config.items('.@host')
print config.get('.@host', 'ip').split('\n')
```

Comment: thanks! It's worked.If ini has two sections "[]",each section has two ".@host". How correspond?

Comment: Huh? Provide another example and i'll take a stab at it.